# Cifs mount problem

Tags: 18.04

Hi I'm trying to mount a smb share on a linux nas at the

Address: 192.168.1.183 / ODROIDXU4-SHARE

Path: Myfiles-Share

I have made a file .smbcredentials under the user "rene" and chmod 600 on it which looks like this:

```
username=rene
password=***********
```

And my fstab looks like this

```
 /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0194-4700  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

#//192.168.1.183/Myfiles-Share /media/odroidxu4-nasshare cifs credentials=/home/rene/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0

//192.168.1.183/Myfiles-Share /media/odroidxu4-nasshare cifs credentials=/home/rene/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

But I get the following error in dmesg:

```
[ 2675.630962] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 2675.630989] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
[ 2899.179580] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 2899.179598] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 2899.179627] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

I can access this share in windows so it works / is active - Anyone who has a possible solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried different values for `sec=`, like `sec=ntlmssp` or `sec=ntlmv2`?

Comment: I made it work with this line:

//192.168.1.183/Myfiles-Share /media/odroidxu4-nasshare cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/rene/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=rene,gid=r$,gid=rene,nofail 0 0

Comment: Don't know how to mark the post as resolved?

Comment: Answer the question yourself, then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with this line:

```
 //192.168.1.183/Myfiles-Share /media/odroidxu4-nasshare cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/rene/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=rene,gid=r$,gid=rene,nofail 0 0 –
```